# Securing Azure Windows VM

Tags: azure, security, vpn, rdp

I am very new to using Azure.
I have created a Windows 10 VM on Azure.
I can connect to the VM via RDP successfully.
I have restricted port access and IP inbound access.

What can I do to secure access control to my VM better so that it is not so easily accessible from anywhere, i.e just directly RDP into the VM from any public space.

I'm not sure if the best way is to go about this is some form of a) two-factor authentication, or b) through the creation of a VPN. Either way, I'm not sure how to go about either.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to restrict access to RDP to your VM is to amend your Network Security Group (NSG) to only allow inbound access on port 3389 from specific source IP address, and add the IP address, addresses or ranges you want to allow.

The other option is to put in place a VPN or ExpressRoute connection and then remove the Public IP altogether, you could then only access the VM over your network.